# Proof verification of the Triangle Inequality for $k$ vectors?

Tags: proof-verification, vectors, vector-analysis

One of my homework problems was to prove an extension of the Triangle Inequality to $k$ vectors through induction, and I produced a five step proof that I think is correct, but I'm unsure that step $3$ can be made without loss of generality.
The proof is as follows:

Assuming the Triangle Inequality, prove with induction that $|| \vec{x}_1 + \dots + \vec{x}_k || \le || \vec{x}_1|| + \dots + ||\vec{x}_k||$ 
$(1) \quad$ Holds for $k=1$ trivially, holds for $k=2$ by Triangle Inequality
$\qquad$ The inductive base case 
$(2) \quad$ Assume $\vec{x}_1 + \dots + \vec{x}_k = \vec{y}$. 
$(3) \quad || \vec{x}_1 + \dots + \vec{x}_k || \le || \vec{x}_1|| + \dots + ||\vec{x}_k||$ 
$\qquad ||\vec{x}_1 + \dots + \vec{x}_{k+1} || \le || \vec{x}_1|| + \dots + ||\vec{x}_{k+1}||$ 
$\qquad$ Subtract these two inequalities.
$\qquad ||\vec{x}_1 + \dots + \vec{x}_{k+1} || - || \vec{x}_1 + \dots + \vec{x}_k || \le ||\vec{x}_{k+1}||$
$(4) \quad ||\vec{y} + \vec{x}_{k+1}|| - ||\vec{y}|| \le ||\vec{x}_{k+1}||$
$\qquad$ Substitute
$(5) \quad ||\vec{y} + \vec{x}_{k+1}|| \le ||\vec{y}|| + ||\vec{x}_{k+1}||$
$\qquad$ Rearrange
True by Triangle Inequality, concluding the proof.

Can step $(3)$ be made without loss of generality? The rest of the proof looks correct to me.

Comment: No in step (3) you're succumbing to circular reasoning. You've just assumed what you need to prove.

Comment: And in any case, you can't subtract inequalities. For example, $3 \leq 5$ and $2 \leq 5$ but $(3 - 2) \nleq (5 - 5)$.

Comment: You should also use a different variable to $k$ in your hypothesis step, as you need to assume that it's true for some fixed arbitrary integer $n \geq 1$.

Comment: I didn't even read that far but quite right. The best you can do is subtract the same element from both sides of the inequality.

Comment: Could I follow the same vein of thought and correct the proof?

Comment: Not really because the second step in your inductive argument (3) makes the rest invalid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your step $3$ is not correct since it uses the fact that

> $$\qquad ||\vec{x_1} + \dots + \vec{x_{k+1}} || \le || \vec{x_1}|| + \dots + ||\vec{x_{k+1}}||$$ and $$\qquad ||\vec{x_1} + \dots + \vec{x_{k+1}} || \le || \vec{x_1}|| + \dots + ||\vec{x_{k+1}}||$$

are true and then deduce an expression which is valid by triangle inequality. But your actual job was to prove the triangle inequality itself. So you have circular reasoning.

**Better approach to this problem:**

Assume that the inequality is valid for $k$ vectors.

So we have that $$\qquad ||\vec{x_1} + \dots + \vec{x_{k}} || \le || \vec{x_1}|| + \dots + ||\vec{x_{k}}||$$

For $k+1$ vectors, we can state that
$$\qquad ||\vec{x_1} + \dots + \vec{x_{k+1}}||$$
$$\le ||\vec{x_1} + \dots + \vec{x_{k}}|| + ||\vec{x_{k+1}}||$$ 
$$\le || \vec{x_1}|| + \dots + ||\vec{x_{k}}|| + ||\vec{x_{k+1}}||$$

So it is true for $k+1$ vectors.

The result is true by induction.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

$||v_1+v_2+...+ v_k + v_{k+1}|| = ||y + v_{k+1}|| < ||y|| + ||v_{k+1}|| < ||v_1|| + ||v_2|| ...+ ||v_k|| + ||v_{k+1}||$.